# Machine Learning Algorithm for multiple output features

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am looking for machine learning algorithm where I have multiple variables as output . It is something like like a vector[A,....X] each of which can have 0 or 1 value. I have data to train the model with required input features. 
Which algorithm should I use for such case. With my limited knowledge  I know that multi label classification can solve the problem where one output variable can take multiple values like color. But this case is multiple output variables taking 0 or 1 . Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give an answer on which algorithm is the best without more information.
A perceptron, a neural network with an output layer with multiple binary (threshold function) neurons could be a good candidate.

Comment: Hi Aggelos, Thanks for response , can you let me know few suitable algorithms  which I should investigate ?

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, there a few algorithms you can check. I suggest you spend some time doing a bit of research and then post again with specific  questions, if needed. This seems like a good starting point: https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/aly05multiclass.pdf. Hope it helps.